# gulp watch not working properly

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

So I've got a problem with my `gulp.watch` task. So the short version of my `gulpfile.js` is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    usemin = require('gulp-usemin'),
    wrap = require('gulp-wrap'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    minifyJs = require('gulp-uglify'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    minifyHTML = require('gulp-minify-html'),
    rimraf = require('gulp-rimraf'),
    live = require('gulp-livereload'),
    strip = require('gulp-strip-debug'),
    gulpif = require('gulp-if');

var paths = {styles: 'public-src/less/*.*'};

gulp.task('delete-css', function (cb) {
    return gulp.src(paths.css_delete)
        .pipe(rimraf());
});

gulp.task('custom-less', ['delete-css'], function (cb) {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles)
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});
gulp.task('watch', function () {

    gulp.watch([paths.styles],['custom-less']);

});
```

Also I've got a build task which contains custom-less task, which actually works. Here it is

```
gulp.task('build-custom', ['custom-less']);

gulp.task('build', ['build-custom']);
```

So when i ran `gulp build` css is concatenated to one file. When I edit my css in terminal I see that `task custom-less` is starting and finished, but the css file does not get updated. I cant seem to understand why the same task works when you run it using `gulp build` but when you watch it, it does not change...

Hope anyone has ideas?

Comment: Maybe your editing a file in a sub-folder of public-src/less/ ? You should then define paths.styles like 'public-src/less/**/*.*'. For what you're saying, your problem is with gulp.watch not watching the file you're modifying, so play with the gulp.watch parameters.

Comment: For that matter, you can just say `*` instead of `*.*`

Comment: @Sergeon no, I've got only 1 file, it is actually a css file (not less) that I modify, the problem is that it detects that I am making changes, but does nothing.

Comment: @henry it does not help

Comment: you didn't define styles.path_delete in your example. Is it defined in your real gulpfile?

Comment: @Sergeon i forgot to copy, yes it is actually included. The problem was with that I forgot to run another task, that minifies the output files and puts them to /lib/css folder... Silly mistake. Thx for you help.

Comment: No that won't fix your problem, just letting you know it's equivalent and shorter

Comment: @henry oh, so a bit pointless to point that out then...

Comment: One of the uses of comments on SO is to point out side things. Your use of `*.*` where the standard is to use `*` suggests you're new to gulp globbing so I let you know how it's usually written